# QTreeWidget activate item signals

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreewidget

I need to do some actions when item in QTreeWidget activates, but following code doestn't gives me expected result:

```
class MyWidget(QTreeWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("activated(QModelIndex)"), self.editCell)


    def editCell(self, index):
        print index
```

or

```
 class MyWidget(QTreeWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
         self.connect(self, SIGNAL("itemActivated(QTreeWidgetItem, int)"),
                      self.editCell)


     def editCell(self, item, column=0):
         print item
```

What am i doing wrong or how to hadnle item activation in the right way?

Thanks in advance,
Serge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtreewidget.html#itemActivated) the description of the signal you're looking for has an asterisk.

```
QTreeWidget::itemActivated(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)
```

This means your connect call should look like this:

```
self.connect(self, SIGNAL("itemActivated(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)"), self.editCell)
```

---

PyQt has a nice [new API to connect signals](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals) (since version 4.6 I believe). I recommend using it.

```
self.itemActivated.connect(self.editCell)
```